# Raspberry Pi: open browser using bash and crontab

Tags: bash, browser, cron, chromium, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup a simple bash script. I want to open the browser.

`chromium-browser <url>` works if I do it in the cli or in the bash script if I run the script by ./scrpt.

But if I put that script in crontab, which is what I really want I get. 
`(chromum:xxxx) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

I added `export DISPLAY=:1` and now I get `Client is not authrized to connect to the Server   (chromum:xxxx) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display 1`

I'm not sure if the export line is helpful or needed, but I was it suggested else where. Using 0 gives an error about protocol. Also other browsers cause errors too, ill use whatever browser. I've had the same issue with `x-www-browser`

Comment: Where is your XServer? You can probably fix this with `DISPLAY=:1 xhost +` on the machine that it runs on. Whether that's a good idea is another question :)

Comment: Please note that there is also [raspberrypi.se]. If you don't get an answer here, you can flag this question and ask for it to be migrated there.

Comment: Why are you attempting to open a web browser from a cron job?

Comment: My xserver is local to the rpi Its either 0 or 1.    I knew someone would ask why, I get that its odd, but I want to generate regular occurrence of a script that I wrote for generating traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL points to a web app that you manage, consider using AJAX to update the page contents, rather than cron.